# Use load/store correctly

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, sse, simd

How to use load/store to do aligned `int16_t` byte swapping correctly?

```
void byte_swapping(uint16_t* dest, const uint16_t* src,
                              size_t count) {
    __m128i _s, _d;
    for (uint16_t const * end(dest + count); dest != end; dest += 8, src += 8)
    {
        _s = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)src);
        _d = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_epi16(_s, 8), _mm_srli_epi16(_s, 8));
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i*) dest, _d);
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having ? If it's just that the buffer is not correctly aligned then either fix the alignment or use `_mm_loadu_si128`/`_mm_storeu_si128`.

Comment: I tried _mm_loadu_si128/_mm_storeu_si128 , it also crashed in VS 2015 .or any other way to write this 16 byte swapping uisng SSE intrinsics ?

Comment: The code looks OK from what you've show us - can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/mcve) ?

Comment: so from the VS 2015 break , what do you think the problem is ?

Comment: Without an MCVE it's almost impossible to help you. The only obvious bug I see is that your routine will fail if `count` is not a multiple of 8 - that seems to be why your particular example has crashed, since 172 is not a multiple of 8.

Comment: Just wonder what is MCVE ? so in my case , what should be done to do this byte swapping correct ? (align to 8 ?)

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is described in the help pages (sorry - I tihnk the link above was broken) - it's just a minimal compilable program that reproduces the problem. As for fixing your bug, you either need to ensure that count is always a multiple of 8, or fix your for loop so that it terminates correctly and then handle any residual elements either using scalar code or a masked SIMD iteration.

Comment: I've added a fixed version of your code as an answer (below) now.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will fail when `count` is not a multiple of 8, or when either `src` or `dest` is not 16 byte aligned.

Here is a fixed (and tested) version of your code:

```
void byte_swapping(uint16_t* dest, const uint16_t* src, size_t count)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i + 8 <= count; i += 8)
    {
        __m128i s = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&src[i]);
        __m128i d = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_epi16(s, 8), _mm_srli_epi16(s, 8));
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&dest[i], d);
    }
    for ( ; i < count; ++i) // handle residual elements
    {
        uint16_t w = src[i];
        w = (w >> 8) | (w << 8);
        dest[i] = w;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul .Let me try it out tonight .Actually we are working on a xbox 360 emulator which progressing very well .                                                                                           https://github.com/benvanik/xenia

Comment: It comes close and looks better but it somehow cutoff like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/pT9GP.jpg

Comment: OK - I suspect the bug lies elsewhere - you can prove this by replacing `byte_swapping` with a simple scalar implementation - I expect you will see the same result.

Comment: OK - can you include the scalar version in your question ?

Comment: for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  dest[i] = (((src[i] >> 8) & 0xff) | ((src[i] << 8) & 0xff00));
 }

Comment: Can you confirm that `src` and `dest` are actually declared as `uint16_t` in the calling code ?

Comment: yes , i just put in the original code up there for your reference.

Comment: OK - I see the bug now in the scalar clean up loop - see fixed answer above.

Comment: It works now however just wonder if second part i use scalar implementation , would it be any speedup then?

Comment: If you're calling it with N = 172 then you get 21 iterations of the SIMD loop (first 168 elements) and then 4 iterations of the scalar loop (remaining 4 elements). So the cost of the scalar loop should be negligible. Profile it and if it's still a bottleneck then there are possible further optimisations that can be applied, but I doubt that you'll need to.

Comment: I understood now .Just wonder what is a masked SIMD iteration ? and i can replace that scalar code .Just for learning.

Comment: In this case it will make little or no difference, but you can generate a mask for the final 4 elements, then load 8 elements, byte swap them, mask out the 4 elements that should not be modified, and then write back the masked vector. A better solution though is to make sure that the buffers you supply are suitably padded to a multiple of 8 elements, then the scalar loop does not come in to play.

Comment: I see. i pasted another one without using load/store function .Is it correct ? and what is the performance difference between them

Comment: Look at the generated code - it will be much the same - you've just used implicit loads/stores but you've relinquished control over which specific instructions are used. Always benchmark and/or profile the code to see whether it makes any difference, and avoid speculative/premature optimisation. Also, please don't keep editing your question if it's now been answered - accept the above answer if it helped you, and then post a new question as the need arises.

Comment: You're welcome ! For any future questions on SSE, SIMD, etc, be sure to use the `[simd]` or `[sse]` tags - that way I get a notification for the new question and can take a look.

Comment: One last question , if uint32_t and uint64_t , the loop incrememnt will be 4 and 2 respectively right?

Comment: Yes, the vectors are always 16 bytes, so that's 4 x uint32_t or 2 x uint64_t.

Comment: Just wonder this store/load function is emitting v prefixed AVX variants?

Comment: If you're compiling for an AVX target then the compiler should automatically be emitting `V` prefixed SSE instructions. If you're compiling for a non-AVX target then it will just be the normal SSE instructions (without the `V` prefix).

Comment: In MSVC , how to check it?

Comment: I don't use Windows or MSVC - there must be a way to look at generated code though - try the online help ?

Comment: I see. let me try online help

Comment: My `pshufb` answer on your other question is applicable here, too.  Faster than shift/or.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31210956/224132

Comment: Note that `pshufb` requires SSSE3, but that shouldn't be a problem unless you need to support 10 year old CPUs.

Comment: I believe `i+8<=count` is not correct. Try `i<(count & ~7)`

Comment: @Elaifer: what do you think the problem is ? Both do much the same thing, no ?