# SSE byte and half word swapping

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I would like to translate this code using SSE intrinsics.

```c
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < length; i += 4, src += 4, dest += 4)
{
    uint32_t value = *(uint32_t*)src;
    *(uint32_t*)dest = ((value >> 16) & 0xFFFF) | (value << 16);
}
```

Is anyone aware of an intrinsic to perform the 16-bit word swapping?

Comment: Why not just write reusable  code and optimize for the target platform? What compiler are you using?

Comment: This doesn't really qualify as an attempt IMO, at least throw in some intrinsics

Answer (score 6):

`pshufb` (SSSE3) should be faster than 2 shifts and an OR.  Also, a slight modification to the shuffle mask would enable an endian conversion, instead of just a word-swap.

stealing Paul R's function structure, just replacing the vector intrinsics:

```
void word_swapping_ssse3(uint32_t* dest, const uint32_t* src, size_t count)
{
    size_t i;
    __m128i shufmask =  _mm_set_epi8(13,12, 15,14,  9,8, 11,10,  5,4, 7,6,  1,0, 3,2);
    // _mm_set args go in big-endian order for some reason.                       

    for (i = 0; i + 4 <= count; i += 4)
    {
        __m128i s = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&src[i]);
        __m128i d = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s, shufmask);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&dest[i], d);
    }
    for ( ; i < count; ++i) // handle residual elements
    {
        uint32_t w = src[i];
        w = (w >> 16) | (w << 16);
        dest[i] = w;
    }
}
```

`pshufb` can have a memory operand, but it has to be the shuffle mask, not the data to be shuffled.  So you can't use it as a shuffled-load. :/

gcc doesn't generate great code for the loop.  The main loop is

```
# src: r8.  dest: rcx.  count: rax.  shufmask: xmm1
.L16:
        movq    %r9, %rax
.L3:  # first-iteration entry point
        movdqu  (%r8), %xmm0
        leaq    4(%rax), %r9
        addq    $16, %r8
        addq    $16, %rcx
        pshufb  %xmm1, %xmm0
        movups  %xmm0, -16(%rcx)
        cmpq    %rdx, %r9
        jbe     .L16
```

With all that loop overhead, and needing a separate load and store instruction, throughput will only be 1 shuffle per 2 cycles.  (8 uops, since `cmp` macro-fuses with `jbe`).

A faster loop would be

```
  shl $2, %rax  # uint count  ->  byte count
  # check for %rax less than 16 and skip the vector loop
  # cmp / jsomething
  add %rax, %r8  # set up pointers to the end of the array
  add %rax, %rcx
  neg %rax       # and count upwards toward zero
.loop:
  movdqu (%r8, %rax), %xmm0
  pshufb  %xmm1, %xmm0
  movups  %xmm0, (%rcx, %rax)  # IDK why gcc chooses movups for stores.  Shorter encoding?
  add $16, %rax
  jl .loop
  # ...
  # scalar cleanup
```

`movdqu` loads can micro-fuse with complex addressing modes, unlike vector ALU ops, so all these instructions are single-uop except the store, I believe.

This should run at 1 cycle per iteration with some unrolling, since `add` can micro-fuse with `jl`.  So the loop has 5 total uops.  3 of them are load/store ops, which have dedicated ports.  Bottlenecks are: `pshufb` can only run on one execution port (Haswell (SnB/IvB can `pshufb` on ports 1&5)).  One store per cycle (all microarches).  And finally, the 4 fused-domain uops per clock limit for Intel CPUs, which should be reachable barring cache-misses on Nehalem and later (uop loop buffer).

Unrolling would bring the total fused-domain uops per 16B down below 4.  Incrementing pointers, instead of using complex addressing modes, would let the stores micro-fuse.  (Reducing loop overhead is always good: letting the re-order buffer fill up with future iterations means the CPU has something to do when it hits a mispredict at the end of the loop and returns to other code.)

This is pretty much what you'd get by unrolling the intrinsics loops, as Elalfer rightly suggests would be a good idea.  With gcc, try `-funroll-loops` if that doesn't bloat the code too much.

BTW, it's probably going to be better to byte-swap while loading or storing, mixed in with other code, rather than converting a buffer as a separate operation.

Comment: Nice - it might be worth mentioning that `pshufb` requires SSSE3 though.

Comment: Thanks for that reminder.  SSSE3 was introduced with Core2, and is almost 10 years old now, but it would still be bad practice to use it without checking.  (Unlike SSE2, which is non-optional in amd64.)

Comment: Indeed - and I seem to remember that AMD were very late adopting SSSE3 (and SSE4) - I haven't really looked at AMD CPUs in a long time, but I assume they have now caught up ?

Comment: Wow, you're right.  Not until Bulldozer (2011) (which caught AMD up to AVX).  Mainly because Intel doesn't release details very early, or makes a last-minute change.  So AMD has to start designing it in only a short time before Intel has final silicon for sale.  AMD won't have AVX2 CPUs until Excavator (2015).

Comment: AMD was going through a rough patch in 2005 as they lost a lot of their early AMD64 lead to Intel - for some reason they decided to skip SSSE3 and SSE4 and go for what they called SSE5 - but of course compatibility is king, and it's taken long time to fix those mistakes and get (almost) to a level playing field.

Comment: It wasn't until Core2 that Intel recovered from the P4 misadventure.  That came out in 2006, at which point they started eating AMD's lunch.  K10 had SSE4a, but SSE5 (i.e. XOP/other stuff) didn't arrive until Bulldozer.

Comment: You're right - I think I was confusing SSE4a with SSE5. It's been quite a roller coaster ride and I didn't think that AMD would survive but they seem to be hanging on by their fingernails.

Comment: I would recommend to do the unroll on this loop and/or try `#pragma unroll(4)`, but it might be the same as there are usually just 1 shuffle port in the CPU

Answer (score 3):

The scalar code in your question isn't really *byte* swapping (in the sense of endianness conversion, at least) - it's just swapping the high and low 16 bits within a 32 bit word. If this is what you want though then just re-use [the solution to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31177036/253056), with appropriate changes:

```
void byte_swapping(uint32_t* dest, const uint32_t* src, size_t count)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i + 4 <= count; i += 4)
    {
        __m128i s = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&src[i]);
        __m128i d = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_epi32(s, 16), _mm_srli_epi32(s, 16));
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&dest[i], d);
    }
    for ( ; i < count; ++i) // handle residual elements
    {
        uint32_t w = src[i];
        w = (w >> 16) | (w << 16);
        dest[i] = w;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep , you are right .It is another endianness conversion .Thanks for the help.

Comment: Heh, I just had a look at this.  gcc 4.9.2 amd64 auto-vectorizes the cleanup loop and generates a boatload of int code, as well as another copy of the vector loop.  /facepalm.

Comment: I suspect that `pshufb` would be more efficient than 2 shifts + an or.

Comment: @PeterCordes: you're probably right, but then again there is so little going on between loads and stores it may well be I/O bound.

Comment: If the buffers are in L1 or L2 cache, then you can sustain a 128b load and store every clock.  While writing my answer, it turned out that minimizing loop overhead can double the throughput (for the cached case).  Shift / Or uops instead of a single shuffle mean more uops in the loop, reducing potential throughput.  It's always better to be able to fill the reorder buffer faster, so the CPU has things to do during later pipeline bubbles.

Comment: Yes - I noticed from the OP's previous question that he seems to be applying these routines to images, so the loads/stores may well be touching DRAM, but it certainly doesn't hurt to make the code more efficient regardless.

Comment: You guys are awesome .We're basically AVX target and running the whole xbox 360 emulator with openGL 4.5 compulsory.

Comment: This is actually a 32bit ror by 16, and there is `_mm_ror_epi32` in AVX512 spec. Just wait for another year ;) Performance wise, it should be better to do `pshufb` vs. `2*shift` on most architecture, but might be the same where Intel has 2 shift ports.